# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler 10.0.0.0 missing from GAC during Clickonce deployment

Tags: clickonce, gac

Activation context generation failed for "C:\Users\dblevins\AppData\Local\Temp\Deployment\ZO3Y9OE2.WT7\945T7AWT.NMQ\Y3WDH4YP.YOA\XWZK83H3.JN9.manifest". Dependent Assembly Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler,processorArchitecture="amd64",publicKeyToken="B03F5F7F11D50A3A",version="10.0.0.0" could not be found. Please use sxstrace.exe for detailed diagnosis.

Not sure how to resolve this one. This seems to happen only on specific machines.

I can't find the dll in question on my machine's GAC either.

Answer (score 0):

This took me a day to figure out:

- I was building my .NET 4.5 ClickOnce Application on a Teamcity build server
- The app installed and worked on multiple computers.
- As the first client throw this error I investigated the build log and found this message `[13:43:25][GenerateApplicationManifest] C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(3240, 5): warning MSB3187: Referenced assembly C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler\v4.0_10.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler.dll targets a different processor than the application`

The app is declared as x86 and this was the first client with x86 but the warning tells me that an assembly from GAC_64 is included, weird.

I found a blog post suggesting to install NET 4.5 SDK via Microsoft SDK Installer but I was unsure which SDK to take since the build server runs Windows 7 and NET 4.5 seems to be included in Windows 8 SDK

Long story short, I installed Visual Studio 2013 and now the build log does not contain a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities.Compiler` anymore and the ClickOnce application runs fine.